# Manipulations with Bernoulli numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, bernoulli-numbers

Is there a simple way to rewrite the expression
$$ c(g):= \sum_{k=0}^{2g} \frac{B_k B_{2g-k}}{k! (2g-k)!} (-1)^k $$
involving a sum of Bernoulli numbers, as a product of just one or two Bernoulli numbers, times possibly a numerical coefficient depending on $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think I found the answer by myself: it is $c_0=1$ and
$$ c_{g \geq 1} = - \frac {B_{2g}}{2g (2g-2)!}$$
and it is obtained by differentiating the generating function,
$$ \frac {d}{dt} \frac{1}{e^t-1}$$